# what are default values for asp.net RijndaelManaged class properties

Tags: asp.net, encryption, rijndaelmanaged

what are default values for RijndaelManaged class properties KeySize , BlockSize , FeedbackSize and Padding ? 
and are default values the best too or not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the parameterless constructor of Rijndeal class (RijndaelManaged inherits form that class)

```
protected Rijndael()
{
    this.KeySizeValue = 256;
    this.BlockSizeValue = 128;
    this.FeedbackSizeValue = this.BlockSizeValue;
    this.LegalBlockSizesValue = Rijndael.s_legalBlockSizes;
    this.LegalKeySizesValue = Rijndael.s_legalKeySizes;
}
```

What are the best values, that is hard to say, it depends from your usage. That's way they are defined as properties :)

Comment: thank you , what about paddingMode ? what is recommended to be set ?

Comment: default is this.PaddingValue = PaddingMode.PKCS7; for more see http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1486/how-to-choose-a-padding-mode-with-aes

Comment: Is CBC the default chaining mode?

Comment: In all classes that derive from SymmetricAlgorithm use CBC, look under remarks https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the "System.Security.Cryptography" class which Rijndael inherits from, this is what you will see in the comments.

```
// Summary:
//     Gets or sets the padding mode used in the symmetric algorithm.
//
// Returns:
//     The padding mode used in the symmetric algorithm. The default is System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.PKCS7.
//
// Exceptions:
//   T:System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException:
//     The padding mode is not one of the System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode values.

public virtual PaddingMode Padding { get; set; }
```